# Issue With Getting Deep Water (H2O) Set Up in R

Tags: r, deep-learning, gpu, h2o

I am having trouble getting DeepWater up and running in R via H2O. I have downloaded the most recent .jar file ( I think) but I get the following error this install command:

```
install.packages("C:\\Users\\..\\Documents\\R\\win-
library\\3.4\\h2o_3.10.3.99999.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source",
lib="C:\\Users\\..\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.4")
* installing *source* package 'h2o' ...
** R Error in .install_package_code_files(".", instdir) :  files in 'C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpuyZ5fc/R.INSTALL3783508571d/h2o/R' missing from 'Collate' field:   xgboost.R ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package 'h2o'
* removing 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.4/h2o'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.4/h2o' Warning in install.packages :   running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\...\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" "C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.4/h2o_3.10.3.99999.tar.gz"' had status 1 Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.4/h2o_3.10.3.99999.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status Error in if (file.exists(dest) && file.mtime(dest) > file.mtime(lib) &&  :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we had some unused deps in one of our files in version `3.10.3.x`, the one you're using.

It should be fixed in the newest version, which is `3.11.0.X` and which you can get from [here](https://www.h2o.ai/download/).

@Edit:

The above version was built for Linux, though - if you want to run it on windows you'll have to build it yourself according to the instructions [here for deepwater](https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater) and [here for h2o](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3). We don't have nightly builds for Windows just yet.

Comment: "build it yourself according to the instructions here for deepwater ..."
The word "windows" is never mentioned there :-(

Comment: @Dan yes, unfortunately we haven't tested it on Windows machines. Would be good to test it and eventually add necessary fixes (as well as add new features) but unfortunately the team is pretty spread out now across other projects.

Comment: I see. Just to mention it: I'm fine with Linux, but we're at a huge company here with Windows laptops and no admin rights. Somebody around here would possible even pay for Windows functionality before they let us play with different OSs.